# Thesis Theme Custom Loop

Tags: comments

I am building a website using Thesis theme and am using Thesis Custom Loop API with custom WP_Query . When I do this on single page it doesn't show the comments form. How can I add a comment form on the single post page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this code after the loop:

```
<?php comment_form(); ?>
```